# Let's Encrypt with HApRoxy on GKE

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, haproxy, lets-encrypt

I am following some articles to implement SSL on my application. But not able to understand how to generate the certificate or do I need to generate the certificate or not?

The main thing is, in concept, I am not able to put the things together.

Let me explain the situation.

I am running an application "User Registration" (REST API Based) in GKE cluster with HAProcxy Ingress Controller and HTTP(S) L7 loadbalancer. I have an existing domain (e.g. mydomain.com) where I am hosting my website. The hosting platform has provided a SSL certificate which is securing wild card domain (*.mydomain.com) and my website opens with http(colon)(slash slash) mydomain.com. I have created a subdomain apps.mydomain.com and pointed "A" record to the GCP HTTP(S) loadbalancer IP, so that I can access the application over the internet. I can access my application over the internet on port 80. But it does not work on Post 443 (with https).

In the articles, I need to generate a certificate and key using ACME and the same need to be used in Cluster Issuer and Ingress.

Ref# digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

Do I need to ask my domain/hosting provider for the Certificate and Key?
Or I can use ACME to generate another certificate with hostname: apps.mydomain.com?

Even I downloaded the certificate and key from my hosting provided website (there was an option - user you own server) and used the same in the Ingress only (used the certificate and ley as a secret). But my website turned into an insecure mode and when curl the API https://apps.mydomain.com/CreteUser there was an error:

### TCP_NODELAY set

- schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
- schannel: SSL/TLS connection with apps.mydomain.com port 443 (step 2/3)
- schannel: encrypted data got 1845
- schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 1845 length 4096
- schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
- Closing connection 0
- schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with demo.apps.product.barnsleypujo.co.uk port 443
- schannel: clear security context handle
  curl: (35) schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.

Could you please help me out?

Thanks,
Suvendu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The star in the certificate subject (`*.example.com`) means you can replace the first domain name component of the name with anything you want, e.g. `apps.example.com`, `mail.example.com`, etc.

[RFC2818](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt) states:

> If more than one identity of a given type is present in the
>   certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one of
>   the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
>   character * which is considered to match any single domain name
>   component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but
>   not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.

In your error message you have the name `demo.apps.product.example.com` what does not match the wildcard certificate and therefore gives the error `SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL`.

To workaround this problem replace the dots e.g. `demo-apps-product.example.com` or something completely different without the dots.

Comment: Thanks for you guidence. I changed the url to apps.mydomain.com and it worked fine.

Comment: Glad I could help out, I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct.